# Show a Dialog When Users Login for the First Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm currently showing users a dialog if they're not following anyone within my app, but I only want to show this whenever it's the users first time logging in? Whenever a new users logs in for the first time, they're not following anyone, so their feed doesn't have any posts, so it shows the dialog. I'm achieving that using the following code:

```
   <% if @posts.any? %>
```

I'm wanting to show a dialog on the users first login, and then it never appear again. I know Deivse has a sign_in_count option, but the dialog would stay there until a users logs out and logs back in.

Comment: You're not really telling us enough to work with.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you add the [`:trackable`](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Trackable) module to your Devise setup, you'll get a `last_sign_in_at` and `sign_in_count`. Either of these should provide you with more than enough information to know when/if a user previously signed in. And `posts.any?` should probably go away.

For instance:

```
display_dialog unless current_user.last_sign_in_at.present?
```

or

```
display_dialog unless current_user.sign_in_count > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

**in controller**

```
if @posts.blank? && user.sign_in_count == 1 # no posts and 1st time login
  session[:display_dialog] = true
ens
```

**in view**

```
<%= display_dialog if session[:display_dialog] %>
```